# Are PWA's supported in the app store? IOS 14

Tags: ios, app-store, progressive-web-apps, ios14

So, i want to make an web app that is a mobile app too. And i don't really know if the you can add a PWA to the app store. I'v read few articales about hosting PWA's and it still isn't clear for me if its possible or not to add it on app store.

Comment: PWAs are not supported in the App Store. All App Store apps must be compiled to native code. There may be tools out there to convert a PWA to native code, but don't ask me what they are. I don't know.

Comment: Thanks Its kinda anoyoing but its apple.

Comment: @Paulw11 , there are quite a lot, can some one name a few ..

Comment: You can wrap it in a web view and submit that as a native app, but it is against App Store rules to simply have an app that loads a PWA into a web view from a server; the executable needs to be fully contained in the app bundle.  See [2.5.2](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements)